# Is there a way to delay the on_changed() call for matplotlib sliders?

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, tkinter, slider

I am currently working to create a tkinter GUI which shows a matplotlib figure with two sliders.  The sliders are to be used for selecting a range of data (they are connected to vertical lines on the plot).

The issue I am running into is that when I change the sliders quickly a few times the GUI freezes.  I believe this is due to the **on_changed()** call I am using to make the sliders update.  When you move the slider quickly I believe on_changed() is being called multiple times at a faster rate than the program can keep up with, thus causing the freeze.

Is there any way to add a delay to the on_changed() call so it only looks to see if the slider has been changed every given interval of time (ex. 100 ms)?

Below is example code I found which freezes in the way I described.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook
from tkinter import Canvas
from tkinter import messagebox as msg

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons



class LukeOutline(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        # Inherit from tk.Tk
        super().__init__()

        # Title and size of the window
        self.title('Luke Outline')
        self.geometry('600x400')

        # Create the drop down menus
        self.menu = tk.Menu(self,bg='lightgrey',fg='black')

        self.file_menu = tk.Menu(self.menu,tearoff=0,bg='lightgrey',fg='black')
        self.file_menu.add_command(label='Add Project',command=self.unfinished)

        self.menu.add_cascade(label='File',menu=self.file_menu)

        self.config(menu=self.menu)

        # Create the tabs (Graph, File Explorer, etc.)
        self.notebook = Notebook(self)

        graph_tab = tk.Frame(self.notebook)
        file_explorer_tab = tk.Frame(self.notebook)

        # Sets the Graph Tab as a Canvas where figures, images, etc. can be added
        self.graph_tab = tk.Canvas(graph_tab)
        self.graph_tab.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=1)

        # Sets the file explorer tab as a text box (change later)
        self.file_explorer_tab = tk.Text(file_explorer_tab,bg='white',fg='black')
        self.file_explorer_tab.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=1)

        # Add the tabs to the GUI
        self.notebook.add(graph_tab, text='Graph')
        self.notebook.add(file_explorer_tab, text='Files')

        self.notebook.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        # Add the graph to the graph tab
        self.fig = Figure()
        graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig,self.graph_tab)
        graph.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top',fill='both',expand=True)
        EllipseSlider(self.fig)

    #------------------------------------------------------
    def quit(self):
        '''
        Quit the program
        '''
        self.destroy()

    #------------------------------------------------------
    def unfinished(self):
        '''
        Messagebox for unfinished items
        '''
        msg.showinfo('Unfinished','This feature has not been finished')

    #------------------------------------------------------
    def random_graph(self):
        x = list(range(0,10))
        y = [i**3 for i in x]

        fig = Figure()
        axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        axes.plot(x,y,label=r'$x^3$')
        axes.legend()

        return fig

#----------------------------------------------------------

class EllipseSlider():

    #------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self,fig):
        self.fig = fig

        # Initial values
        self.u = 0.     #x-position of the center
        self.v = 0.     #y-position of the center
        self.a = 2.     #radius on the x-axis
        self.b = 1.5    #radius on the y-axis

        # Points to plot against
        self.t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

        # Set up figure with centered axes and grid
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.set_aspect(aspect='equal')
        self.ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
        self.ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
        self.ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
        self.ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
        self.ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
        self.ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
        self.ax.set_xlim(-2,2)
        self.ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
        self.ax.grid(color='lightgray',linestyle='--')

        # Initial plot
        self.l, = self.ax.plot(self.u+self.a*np.cos(self.t),
            self.v+self.b*np.sin(self.t),'k')

        # Slider setup
        self.axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
        self.axb = self.fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=self.axcolor)
        self.axa = self.fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=self.axcolor)

        self.sb = Slider(self.axb, 'Y Radius', 0.1, 2.0, valinit=self.b)
        self.sa = Slider(self.axa, 'X Radius', 0.1, 2.0, valinit=self.a)

        # Call update as slider is changed
        self.sb.on_changed(self.update)
        self.sa.on_changed(self.update)

        # Reset if reset button is pushed
        self.resetax = self.fig.add_axes([0.8,0.025,0.1,0.04])
        self.button = Button(self.resetax, 'Reset', color=self.axcolor, hovercolor='0.975')

        self.button.on_clicked(self.reset)

        # Color button setup
        self.rax = self.fig.add_axes([0.025, 0.5, 0.15, 0.15], facecolor=self.axcolor)
        self.radio = RadioButtons(self.rax, ('red', 'blue', 'green'), active=0)

        self.radio.on_clicked(self.colorfunc)

    #------------------------------------------------------

    def update(self, val):
        '''
        Updates the plot as sliders are moved
        '''
        self.a = self.sa.val
        self.b = self.sb.val
        self.l.set_xdata(self.u+self.a*np.cos(self.t))
        self.l.set_ydata(self.u+self.b*np.sin(self.t))

    #------------------------------------------------------

    def reset(self, event):
        '''
        Resets everything if reset button clicked
        '''
        self.sb.reset()
        self.sa.reset()

    #------------------------------------------------------

    def colorfunc(self, label):
        '''
        Changes color of the plot when button clicked
        '''
        self.l.set_color(label)
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()

#----------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    luke_gui = LukeOutline()
    luke_gui.mainloop()
    es = EllipseSlider()
```

(UPDATE):

I have implemented the correction you showed and the code looks to work as intended except the vertical sliders I am using now do not update their position until I move the slider a second time.  Please see the section from my code below:

```
        # Call update if slider is changed
        self.sa.on_changed(self.schedule_update)
        self.sb.on_changed(self.schedule_update)

    def update(self, value):
        print(value)
        self.vert_a.set_xdata(value)
        self.vert_b.set_xdata(self.sb.val)
        root.update()

    def schedule_update(self, new_value):
        if self.after_id:
            root.after_cancel(self.after_id)
        self.after_id = root.after(1000, self.update, new_value)


root = tk.Tk()
mainapp = MainApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter has a method named `after` for delaying the execution of a command. Your slider can use this to delay the effect of the slider for a second or two. If the slider moves, it can cancel the previously scheduled command and submit a new one.

Here's an example using plain tkinter for simplicity. Run the code and then move the slider quickly or slowly. You'll see that the label will only update after you haven't moved the slider for a full second.

```
import tkinter as tk


after_id = None
def schedule_update(new_value):
    global after_id
    if after_id:
        root.after_cancel(after_id)
    after_id = root.after(1000, update_label, new_value)

def update_label(new_value):
    label.configure(text=f"New value: {new_value}")

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="", width=20)
scale = tk.Scale(
    root, from_=1, to=100,
    orient="horizontal", command=schedule_update
)

label.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=20, pady=(10,0))
scale.pack(side="bottom", fill="x", padx=20, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  I tried implementing the fix as you showed above, but I now have an issue where the vertical sliders I am using do not update to the new position until I move the slider a second time. I will post a sample of my code once I figure out how to

Comment: I updated the main post to show the new issue.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Heath: a question should focus on a single issue.

Comment: My bad, I'll start a new thread.  Thank again for your help.